# How to declare a version of a local copy of existing package

Tags: package, version-support

Is it possible to identify the *package* version of a local copy/clone/fork of a Elpa supported existing package?

**Problem Scenario:**

- A Elpa supported package (lets called it `package-foo`) hosted on some Elpa compliant sites like GNU Elpa or MELPA has some problems.  There might be several Pull Requests waiting for incorporation that have been sitting there for some time.
- Let's say I clone the Git repo of that package and do the merge of the waiting fixes, potentially with some of my own fixes, pushing this all back to my hosted repo and potentially providing that as another PR on the original `package-foo` repo.
- I install this clone of `package-foo` in a directory I put in my `load-path`.

All is fine and dandy I can use the `package-foo` without any problem.  It does not have a *package version* though.

- Now, if another package, lets say `package-bar` requires version X.Y of `package-foo` I run into a problem as Emacs will complain not being able to find it.

Is there a way I can identify a version to my copy of the `package-foo`?

**What does not work**:

- I tried creating a `package-foo-pkg` file that I placed inside my extra directory that is in load-path (`~/.emacs.d/utils`), but it is not recognized (perhaps it is placed in the load-path too late?).

**Work-around that works**

- I install the original `package-foo` inside the `~/.emacs.d/elpa` directory so it can be recognized by Emacs.
- The modified `package-foo` is inside `~/.emacs.d/utils`.
- `load-path` has `~/.emacs.d/utils` before `~/.emacs.d/elpa`, so Emacs loads the modified `package-foo` but is able to see the package version that is specified in the file stored inside `~/.emacs/elpa`.

The disadvantage of this work-around is duplication plus the extra directory in `~/.emacs.d/elpa` causing a little extra processing on Emacs startup.

The real solution to my problem would be the integration of the provided pull-request into the parent package.  But I have no control over this.

**Question:**
Is there a way I can use to assign a package version to my copy of `package-foo` that is located inside my secondary directory `~/.emacs.d/utils/`?

Comment: Do the commands `M-x package-install-file` and `M-x package-install-from-buffer` solve your issue?

Comment: It's a work-around only.  I store package-foo.el and I create a package-foo-pkg.el file that identifies the version x.y, inside a utils directory. Then calling (package-install-file "utils/package-foo.el") creates a elpa/package-foo-x.y  directory with package-foo.el, package-foo-pkg.el and package-foo-autoloads.el.  I don't need to put utils in my load-path.  But if the package-foo has several files, I can't find a way to get them all in the created elpa/package-foo.x.y.    Is there a way to handle this without having to create a elpa/package-foo.x.y directory?

Comment: Besides, another reason I'm trying to not create the extra elpa/package-foo.x.y directory is the time consumed by the package mechanism to process all dependencies and loading when Emacs starts.  As the number of package grows this seems to consume a large percentage of the Emacs startup time. Startup time does not increase when several Emacs Lisp files are stored inside one directory that is inside the load path.  Then one directory can be processed for several files, not one directory per package as its the case for elpa based it seems.

Comment: An extra test I did: I removed the package-foo.el and package-foo.elc from the elpa/package-foo.x.y directory only leaving the package-foo-pkg.el and package-foo-autoloads.el files inside that directory.  The real package-foo.el is inside a separate directory, my utils directory.  That also works.  Emacs starts and does not complain about version x.y of package-foo missing.  So it looks like creating the directory with the -pkg.el and the -autoloads.el is good enough.  Emacs still has to process that extra directory that is put in my load-path though.  I'd like to eliminate that.

Comment: In the end, I'd still like to find a way to inform Emacs that my utils/package-foo.el is version x.y of that package, without having to add an extra directory inside ~/.emacs.d/elpa with adds a new entry in load-path.

Comment: Ok; I had thought the goal was to install a custom version of the library under the elpa directory.  You can speed up initialisation in Emacs 27+ -- look for "New 'package-quickstart' feature." in NEWS (`C-h n`) or NEWS.27 if you're running a later version.

Comment: Thanks. I will.  Does the new package-quickstart also allow tagging a file located in a given directory as a specific version of a package?

Comment: Thanks. I just did that.  I am using several versions of Emacs, including 26.3 and 27.2   I did setup package-quickstart user-option to t in my customization file (via customize-motion) but with Emacs 27.2 I did not see any speedup: I saw a slowdown. Testing with benchmark-init.   Aside from setting package-quickstart to t, is there something else to do?   Also, does the new package-quickstart also allow tagging a file located in a given directory as a specific version of a package?

Comment: Maybe `package-directory-list` helps you.  I have no experience with it.

Comment: OK, thanks I will look into that.

Comment: If you're seeing a slowdown then I *suspect* you're calling `package-initialize` in your init file, in which case you're doing *both* the slow and the fast init processes.

Comment: I've always felt that it would be much better if the package management was using only one directory instead of several, one per package. At this moment I have 177 packages in elpa.  My load-path has 210 entries.  Emacs Lisp does not support directory-based packages the way Python does. It has only one name space for function and one for data. Why separate all of that?  And pay the cost every time Emacs start?

Comment: @phils You are correct in your assumption about my init wrt.  `package-initialize`.  I will have to modify it.  What i have is similar to https://github.com/pierre-rouleau/pel/blob/master/example/init/init-5.el . I have built PEL to be able to control Emacs entirely from customization and have the ability to add and remove packages easily.  I'll have to read a bit more on package quickstart to support post 27.1 and pre-27.  Will do that tomorrow.

Comment: @phils Thanks for the info. I updated my init for emacs > 27 and I confirm that it does speed up.  benchmark-init reported a startup of about 0.84 sec on Emacs 27.2 and now I have about .54 sec instead. On that system my load-path is 177 directories long, with 143 being elpa directories.     I still believe there should really be only 1 directory holding all elpa specific files though.  But that's a different topic and not related to my question that remains.